# Combinatorics Question for Elementary-Grade Contest

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

The below question is from a book geared towards 3rd & 4th graders for MathKangaroo contests.

The actual question being asked is the 3rd question which I have listed (At least how many ... etc). I was able to answer the first two questions (I have NOT mentioned them below) but the answer for 3rd one one seems to be different from what I'm getting.

**Question:
Arbax and Lynda wanted to merge their bone collection. Lynda had 10 bones in 4 boxes and Arbax had 11 bones in 5 boxes.
At least how many boxes with at least 3 bones in each were in the merged collection.
Given Answer (from Book):-
The Merged collection had at least one box with at least 3 bones in it.**

***My answer:-***
Assuming that we put 2 in each of the 9 boxes we get to put only 18 of the 21 bones. So, we need to put 1 more each of the three boxes. So, this leaves us with 3 boxes with 3 bones. I dont know how the author seems to be getting just 1 box with 3 bones.

Answer (score 1):

They can choose to put all $21$ bones in one box.